# Multithreading in .NET 4.0 and performance

Tags: multithreading, optimization, asp.net-4.0

I've been toying around with the Parallel library in .NET 4.0. Recently, I developed a custom ORM for some unusual read/write operations one of our large systems has to use. This allows me to decorate an object with attributes and have reflection figure out what columns it has to pull from the database, as well as what XML it has to output on writes.

Since I envision this wrapper to be reused in many projects, I'd like to squeeze as much speed out of it as possible. This library will mostly be used in .NET web applications. I'm testing the framework using a throwaway console application to poke at the classes I've created.

I've now learned a lesson of the overhead that multithreading comes with. Multithreading causes it to run slower. From reading around, it seems like it's intuitive to people who've been doing it for a long time, but it's actually counter-intuitive to me: how can running a method 30 times **at the same time** be slower than running it 30 times sequentially?

I don't think I'm causing problems by multiple threads having to fight over the same shared object (though I'm not good enough at it yet to tell for sure or not), so I assume the slowdown is coming from the overhead of spawning all those threads and the runtime keeping them all straight. So:

- Though I'm doing it mainly as a learning exercise, is this pessimization? For trivial, non-IO tasks, is multithreading overkill? My main goal is speed, not responsiveness of the UI or anything.
- Would running the same multithreading code in IIS cause it to speed up because of already-created threads in the thread pool, whereas right now I'm using a console app, which I assume would be single-threaded until I told it otherwise? I'm about to run some tests, but I figure there's some base knowledge I'm missing to know **why** it would be one way or the other. My console app is also running on my desktop with two cores, whereas a server for a web app would have more, so I might have to use that as a variable as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thread's don't actually all run concurrently.

On a desktop machine I'm presuming you have a dual core CPU, (maybe a quad at most). This means only 2/4 threads can be running at the same time.

If you have spawned 30 threads, the OS is going to have to context switch between those 30 threads to keep them all running. Context switches are quite costly, so hence the slowdown.

As a basic suggestion, I'd aim for 1 thread per CPU if you are trying to optimise calculations. Any more than this and you're not really doing any extra work, you are just swapping threads in an out on the same CPU. Try to think of your computer as having a limited number of workers inside, you can't do more work concurrently than the number of workers you have available.

Some of the new features in the .net 4.0 parallel task library allow you to do things that account for scalability in the number of threads. For example you can create a bunch of tasks and the task parallel library will internally figure out how many CPUs you have available, and optimise the number of threads is creates/uses so as not to overload the CPUs, so you could create 30 tasks, but on a dual core machine the TP library would still only create 2 threads, and queue the . Obviously, this will scale very nicely when you get to run it on a bigger machine. Or you can use something like `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...)` to queue up a bunch of tasks, and the pool will automatically manage how many threads is uses to perform those tasks.

Yes there is a lot of overhead to thread creation, but if you are using the .net thread pool, (or the parallel task library in 4.0) .net will be managing your thread creation, and you may actually find it creates less threads than the number of tasks you have created. It will internally swap your tasks around on the available threads. If you actually want to control explicit creation of actual threads you would need to use the Thread class.

[Some cpu's can do clever stuff with threads and can have multiple Threads running per CPU - see [hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) - but check out your task manager, I'd be very surprised if you have more than 4-8 virtual CPUs on today's desktops]

Comment: Adding a little to what Simon said, the optimum number of threads is a difficult thing to find as it's often dependent on the system load in general and what your code is doing, my best advice is to experiment with a high load to see what yields the best performance.

Comment: @Lazarus. Yes I totally agree, this is very true. And it can be very system specific too. It's the kind of thing you probably want to expose as settings in some way so it can be tweaked on a case by case basis, with some good defaults.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many issues with this that it pays to understand what is happening under the covers. I would highly recommend the "Concurrent Programming on Windows" book by Joe Duffy and the "Java Concurrency in Practice" book. The latter talks about processor architecture at the level you need to understand it when writing multithreaded code. One issue you are going to hit that's going to hurt your code is caching, or more likely the lack of it.

As has been stated there is an overhead to scheduling and running threads, but you may find that there is a larger overhead when you share data across threads. That data may be flushed from the processor cache into main memory, and that will cause serious slow downs to your code.

This is the sort of low-level stuff that managed environments are supposed to protect us from, however, when writing highly parallel code, this is exactly the sort of issue you have to deal with.

A colleague of mine recorded a screencast about the performance issue with Parallel.For and Parallel.ForEach which may help:

http://rocksolidknowledge.com/ScreenCasts.mvc/Watch?video=ParallelLoops.wmv

Answer (score 1):

You're speaking of an ORM, so I presume some amount of I/O is going on.  If this is the case, the overhead of thread creation and context switching is going to be comparatively non-existent.

Most likely, you're experiencing I/O contention: it can be slower (particularly on rotational hard drives, but also on other storage devices) to read the same set of data if you read it out of order than if you read it in-order.  So, if you're executing 30 database queries, it's possible they'll run faster sequentially than in parallel if they're all backed by the same I/O device and the queries aren't in cache.  Running them in parallel may cause the system to have a bunch of I/O read requests almost simultaneously, which may cause the OS to read little bits of each in turn - causing your drive head to jump back and forth, wasting precious milliseconds.

But that's just a guess; it's not possible to really determine what's causing your slowdown without knowing more.

Although thread creation is "extremely expensive" when compared to say adding two numbers, it's not usually something you'll easily overdo.  If your operations are extremely short (say, a millisecond or less), using a thread-pool rather than new threads will noticeably save time.  Generally though, if your operations are that short, you should reconsider the granularity of parallelism anyhow; perhaps you're better off splitting the computation into bigger chunks: for instance, by having a fairly low number of worker tasks which handle entire batches of smaller work-items at a time rather than each item separately.